# Can a ratio of two members of a positive sequence converge to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Can this happen $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=0$ for a sequence $a_n>0$?

Comment: What are some common integer sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For example letting
$$a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$$
yields
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Another example is $a_n=2^{-n^2}$ so $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=2^{-2n-1}=\frac{1/2}{4^n}$.